# Do you have to fully install SQL Server if you want a .NET application to do a remote connection?

Tags: sql-server

I have a .NET application that connects to a local SQL Server 2008 database. Now the application is changing to connect to a remote database.

My question is, if I'm going to install this application in a computer, do I need to fully install the heavy SQL Server for the sake of connecting to the remote database? Or Microsoft have some kind of light (a few MBs) solution to this problem alone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need to install anything (sql server wise) as the client connection classes are not part of the SQL Server setup. They come with the standard .NET framework.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to install full SQL Server.  At most you should install the Client Tools Connectivity feature on a client machine.  This will get you the correct versions of the SQL Native Client and other various providers for connecting to SQL.